# Netbiosd trying to connect outside subnet on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, netbios

I'm working on a mac mini running Mountain Lion. I have LittleSnitch installed to monitor my outgoing connections. However, since a couple of days netbiosd tries to connect to an IP outside my local subnet.

It tries to connect to 192.168.0.13 (on port 445), and my network is 192.168.2.0/24. I have grepped in the /private and /Users folder for the 0.13 IP, but it didn't find anything.

nslookup on that ip also gives no response.

Why does netbios want to connect to this ip specificly?